# Generating Mouse & Keyboard input from one application to another

Tags: unit-testing, input, keyboard, mouse

I have worked with the win32 API and the DirectX API for interpreting input from the user, but haven't found much in the way of generating input that matches original user input.

My goal is to make a program that will run transparently in the background, minimized, or in the quicklaunch area and have that program artificially implant keyboard and mouse input for a third party, full screen application.

I've found some commands for verifying which window has focus, and some code samples for checking the process name or ID of said application, but not as much on generating input via directx or anything else, to simulate legitimate input.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, I want it to register as close to real input as possible to help facilitate automated testing.

My apologies in advance if this question is too general or "under-researched", I'm just not quite sure where to start on this one!

The program will be in either C++ or C# due to my familiarity with those languages.

Comment: Look into hacking forums - not this one.

Comment: Excuse me? I'm not sure what you mean by this. Why "Hacking Forums"? I guess if they have the information then that's good, but do you happen to have one in mind? or a link? or something else to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this:

One app to act as an global keyboard_hock, and then i did send matching patterns to an second app, direct in memory - i used examples from [All-in-one code framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/71395) examples you can download, lock for CSFileMappingServer & CSFileMappingClient (get / set) to memory from two separete processes. And CSWindowsHook project to catch global keyboard events

I was a litle quick, but to send virtual keyboard you can use:

```
BOOL
WINAPI
PostMessageA(
__in_opt HWND hWnd,
__in UINT Msg,
__in WPARAM wParam,
__in LPARAM lParam);
```

But the winow you send to has to be in focus, you can use:

```
BOOL
WINAPI
BringWindowToTop(
__in HWND hWnd);
```

And to get HWIND to the running app, you can use:

```
HWND
WINAPI
FindWindowA(
__in_opt LPCSTR lpClassName,
__in_opt LPCSTR lpWindowName);
```

Comment: If the Application in question uses DirectInput through DirectX will the input given through PostMessage be recognized as regular Input or will it be dismissed by DirectInput?

Also, can you use PostMessage for Mouse Input generation as well?

Thanks for the info either way, I'll try testing it out this evening. :)

Comment: I dont know every detail, but as i understand it, PostMessageA is used to make keyboard virtual (and i have try it and it works), but you can also, capture the mouse event, stream it to memory, and read it from your reciver app, with the examples i gave you.